# PHPUnit with a Zend Framework 2 module

Tags: phpunit, zend-framework2

I'm struggling in getting a PHPUnit test to work with ZF2.

My directory structure looks as follows

```
project
- src
  - config, data, module, public, vendor
  - init_autoloader.php
- test
  - bootstrap.php
  - SimpleTest.php
```

The application itself works well.

Now for running PHPUnit tests, my bootstrap.php looks as follows

```
putenv('ZF2=../src/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library');
$loader = include '../src/vendor/autoload.php';
include '../src/init_autoloader.php';
```

This works for ZF2 related things but does not find my module. I then read that I have to add the following line to my bootstrap.php

```
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include '../src/config/application.config.php');
```

But now I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Mymodule) could not be initialized.' in /Users/_/src/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:139
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to resolve this issue. What did I do wrong? And how can I make this work?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look at this, it worked for me. http://devblog.x2k.co.uk/getting-phpunit-working-with-a-zend-framework-2-mvc-application/

Comment: They use Zend\Mvc\Application::init() the same way I did, so it does not work for me.

Comment: I'm glad to see you got it working. Take a look here to see my working setup https://github.com/vascowhite/ZendMinimumApplication/tree/master/test  if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks, that might come in handy for the next project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime I was able to solve it using `set_include_path()` and `spl_autoload_register()` as described in http://robertbasic.com/blog/unit-testing-zend-framework-2-modules.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue as well.

I solved it by **running phpunit from the root of my ZF2 project** with the following arguments:

```
 ./vendor/bin/phpunit
  --bootstrap ./module/Rest/test/Bootstrap.php
  ./module/Rest/test/RestTest/Controller/RestControllerTest.php
```

my

```
<zf2_project_root>/module/Rest/test/TestConfig.php.dist
```

is setup up to test my **Rest** module as show here:

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Rest' // <- my 'Rest' module is the one I test here.
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            '../../../config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            'module',
            'vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
```

of course, my **./composer.json** contains a reference to phpunit as follow:

```
{
    "require" : {
        ...,
        "phpunit/phpunit" : "3.7.*",
        ...,
    }
}
```

**Note:**

phpunit can also be invoked with bootstrap class only (i.e., whithout specifying the test suite class). Also using the *--colors* flag makes phpunit output more readable:

```
 ./vendor/bin/phpunit
  --colors
  --bootstrap ./module/Rest/test/Bootstrap.php
```