# Zend Framework 2 PHPUnit Test Error

Tags: php, phpunit, zend-framework2, fatal-error

Hi I am currently running through the ZF2 User Guide trying to run a PHPUnit Test on the skeleton application as outlined here http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/unit-testing.html.

But even though I have not edited the Module and have copied all the files from the tutorial every time I run the PHPUnit Test in Zend Studio I get this error

**Error:**

```
Fatal error: Class 'ApplicationTest\Bootstrap' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\exerciseDB\module\Application\test\ApplicationTest\Controller\IndexControllerTest.php on line 24
```

But when I click on the Bootstrap::getServiceManager(); on line 24 Zend Studio takes me to the correct method.

**File Stucture:**

```
module
|_Application
    |_config
    |_language
    |_src
    |_test
       |_ApplicationTest
       |    |_Controller
       |        |_IndexControllerTest.php
       |_Bootstrap.php
       |_phpunit.xml.dist
       |_TestConfig.php.dist
```

Can anyine tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This was a really annoying bug that is somewhat of an irritation.  Your phpunit config seems to be changed slightly from the one on the skeleton application.  To give you direct answer that fixed my issue I did the following...

```
module
|_Application
    |_config
    |_language
    |_src
    |_tests
       |_ZendApplicationModule
       |    |_Framework
       |        |TestCase.php
       |    |_IndexControllerTest.php
       |    |_SampleTest.php
       |_Bootstrap.php
       |_phpunit.xml.dist
       |_TestConfig.php.dist
```

With the base setup as outlined above from the skeleton APP I had to add

```
require_once 'Framework/TestCase.php';
```

To SampleTest.php

For your actual fix you will need to require_once the file that is generating the issue.  That should fix it.

Also make sure to update your autoload_classmap.php

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I do not see a file called SampleTest.php or a TestCase.php in this tutorial http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/unit-testing.html. Could you point me to where I could find example copies of these files please

Comment: Ah i went based on the git checkout I did recently.  Let me take a look at their code.

Comment: I just made a duplication of their code 100% and it runs based on the page you provided.  Are you running phpunit on a *nix box or on your windows box?  It may be a path issue and I don't have windows to test sorry.

Comment: I am running it on a Windows environment in Zend Studio. I will setup a Linux environment on the weekend and give it a test. Thanks for all your help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, sorry I couldn't help more but I wasn't able to reproduce on your instance, when I've done the tests in the past the require once issue fixed my class not found however based on the application actually running on a *nix env I suspect it's an issue with windows paths and the way the tests are bootstrapped.  But at this point it's just guestimating

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue where phpunit was not seeing my "module/Application/test/phpunit.xml.dist" file (I had it miss-spelled)

Try adding the file directly to the command line:
phpunit --bootstrap Bootstrap.php .

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue as well.

I solved it by **running phpunit from the root of my ZF2 project** with the following arguments:

```
 ./vendor/bin/phpunit
  --bootstrap ./module/Rest/test/Bootstrap.php
```

One can also specify the Test suite to use:

```
 ./vendor/bin/phpunit
  --bootstrap ./module/Rest/test/Bootstrap.php
  ./module/Rest/test/RestTest/Controller/RestControllerTest.php
```

more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980033/phpunit-with-a-zend-framework-2-module/19465266#19465266)