# ZF2 model unit test, class not found

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework2

Eh, this one makes my hair fall out...

I did some usefull stuff in zf1 and now I'm struggling to switch to zf2, and to do the thing right, I want to get stuff done TDD-style.

I've set up the Skeleton application, then made two additional modules, called "Weather" and "Airport". I than made a test case for WeatherController which works fine. Than I made a test case for models within Airport module and it fails with :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Airport\Model\Airport' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs...
```

, and the error is triggered here (AirportTableTest.php) :

```
<?php

namespace AirportTest\Model;

use Airport\Model\Airport;
use Airport\Model\AirportTable;
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;

class AirportTableTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {   

    public function testExample() {
        $airport = new Airport(); // - this is not getting loaded and throws the fatal error :(
    }

}
```

The code is based on the Album module example in ZF2 tutorial. The AirportTable model is supposed to interface a SQL table in the DB and the Airport model is written just like the Album model was written in the tutorial. The directory structure is (abbrevated) :

```
/module
  /Airport
    /src
      /Airport
        /Controller
        /Model
          AirportTable.php
          Airport.php
  /Application
  /Weather
/public
/tests
  /module
    /Airport
      /src
        /Airport
          /Controller
          /Model
            AirportTableTest.php
            AirportTest.php
    /Application
    /Weather
  bootstrap.php
  phpunit.xml
/vendor
```

bootstrap.php from tests directory :

```
<?php
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
include __DIR__.'/../init_autoloader.php';
```

The Airport.php with the class that is not being loaded :

```
<?php
namespace Airport\Model;

class Airport
{
    public $icao;
    public $lat;
    public $lng;
    public $metar;

    public function exchangeArray($data){
        $this->icao = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['icao'] : null;
        $this->lat = (isset($data['lat'])) ? $data['lat'] : null;
        $this->lng  = (isset($data['lng'])) ? $data['lng'] : null;
        $this->metar = (isset($data['metar'])) ? $data['metar'] : null;
    }
}
?>
```

The Module.php for Airport module :

```
<?php
namespace Airport;

use Airport\Model\Airport;
use Airport\Model\AirportTable;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Airport\Model\AirportTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('AirportTableGateway');
                    $table = new AirportTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'AirportTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Airport());
                    return new TableGateway('airport', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ),
        );
    }

}
```

So I'm probably missing something pretty obvious, like autoloader things related perhaps ? So, uhm... help maybe (pretty please) ?

Comment: By the way, a model and test set for the 'Weather' module, in the same manner, works just fine, which is even more confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo, I came up with a working solution, although I'm not quite sure whether its smart or completly retarded.

Based on [PHPUnit with a Zend Framework 2 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980033/phpunit-with-a-zend-framework-2-module) I added the line

```
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include '/../config/application.config.php');
```

to the bootstrap.php of the test suite, and now everything works as expected, however I have no idea whatsoever why it would work without this line for the "Weather" module and not for "Airport" module...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the way the ZF2 getting started tutorial lays out tests. I have completed the tutorial and committed the changes to [my own fork of the ZF2 Skeleton Application source](https://github.com/ezk84/ZendSkeletonApplication/tree/master/module/Application/test).

Basically, each module has it's own test suite, with a dedicated Bootstrap file with configuration and a `phpunit.xml` that will tell PHPUnit to load all this when you run your test (so long as you're in the tests directory when running `phpunit`). This helps keep the tests modular.

Comment: Hi, I am using your test repo, but have found the following error. $ vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit module/Application/test
PHPUnit 3.7.29 by Sebastian Bergmann.


Fatal error: Class 'ApplicationTest\Bootstrap' not found in my-dir-path\module\Application\test\ApplicationTest\Controller\IndexControllerTest.php on line 24